# Firebase - Organize Functions Typescript Linter

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The Firebase docs on how to organize your Functions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions) recommend an *index.js* file with the lines

```
const foo = require('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');
exports.foo = foo.foo;
exports.bar = bar.bar;
```

However, when using Typescript, the default linter settings give the error *"Require statement not part of import statement"*

Changing the const variables to either `import foo = require('./foo');` or `import * as foo from './foo'` resolves the linter error, but causes the deployed functions to reside at paths like */foo-foo* rather than just */foo*.

I know I can just disable the linter errors, but I'd like to know what the correct way to handle this is since I'm pretty new to TypeScript.

What is the proper way to handle these exports in typescript such that the deployed URL will be what you expect without using the exact syntax shown in Firebase doc examples?

Comment: How are you getting to know that the deployed functions reside at paths like /foo-foo rather than just /foo? Can you clarify which path you are referring to?

Comment: @Prabir when either serving or deploying the functions, the Firebase CLI reports something like:`functions[us-central1-game]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/<project id>/us-central1/foo-foo).`

Comment: It seems you are making some mistake in the folder structure. For me it works perfectly and gives the functions url as `http://localhost:5000/project-id/us-central1/foo` when serving locally and `https://us-central1-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/foo` when deploying to Firebase functions. Can you show the folder structure of the functions and the output when serving locally and deploying to Firebase functions redacting any sensitive information?

Comment: @Shackleford Hi, were you able to find the solution? My functions are also deploying as /foo-foo